# WebM file binary format

Tags: codec, webm

I am currently trying to understand how WebM format works. I understood that it's a 'container' format that encapsulate video & audio formats.
I was wondering if it exist a table that specify how data are formatted as binary data ([like the one linked here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure)).

I already looked at the [WebM website](https://www.webmproject.org/) (particularly [wiki](http://wiki.webmproject.org/) & [container documentation](https://www.webmproject.org/docs/container/)). I found informations about which datas can be included in a WebM file but not how they are represented as binary values.

I also did an hexdump (with ascii) of a WebM file and I found some readble strings that specify codecs used, etc... but it did not helped me that much.